# Use Pickle file for Topic Classification. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, topic-modeling

I am trying to do **topic classification** using the pickle file of my trained model but i am facing the error "CountVectorizer - Vocabulary wasn't fitted". Can someone please guide me on how to resolve this error.

Training Dataset format:

```
Topic   originalSentence 
Topic1  He has arrived with his sister's two young children.
Topic2  The Lowells have been living off the Colby fortune
Topic3  Fred and Janice Gage, who live off the Lowell  fortune, which would have gone to Alan Colby
```

My Training Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer,TfidfTransformer,CountVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
import pickle

def train_model():
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/ra51646/Desktop/classification_training.csv')
df = df[pd.notnull(df['originalSentence'])]
df.columns = ['topic', 'originalSentence']
df['category_id'] = df['topic'].factorize()[0]
category_id_df = df[['topic', 'category_id']].drop_duplicates().sort_values('category_id')
category_to_id = dict(category_id_df.values)
id_to_category = dict(category_id_df[['category_id', 'topic']].values)
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, min_df=5, norm='l2', encoding='latin-1', ngram_range=(1, 2), stop_words='english')
features = tfidf.fit_transform(df.originalSentence).toarray()
labels = df.category_id
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['originalSentence'], df['topic'], random_state = 0)
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(X_train)
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)
clf_SGD = SGDClassifier().fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train)
clf_inc = Incremental(clf_SGD)
final_model = clf_inc.fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train,classes=np.unique(y_train))
pickle.dump(final_model, open("/Users/ra51646/Desktop/Pickle/topic_classification.pkl","wb"))
```

**(Error to be solved)Code where i use pickle file for Topic classification:**

```
def find_topic1():
model = pickle.load(open("/Users/ra51646/Desktop/Pickle/topic_classification.pkl","rb"))
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
answer = model.predict(count_vect.transform(["Lindy and her family went camping in the Outback"]))
print(answer[0])
return answer
```

I am getting error `NotFittedError: CountVectorizer - Vocabulary wasn't fitted.`
in find_topic method. Please help me resolve this error. How do i use my pickle file(trained model) for topic classification.

Comment: What libraries are you using?
Show the complete code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I have updated my code. i.e Complete code. Do i need to make mode edits?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you are missing an argument to `CountVectorizer` which makes `count_vect` variable **independent** from the pickled model and hence the error. Without the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it is impossible to tell for sure.

Comment: How can i get count_vect arguments from the picke file?
or How can i make this variable independent?

Comment: Dependent, not independent. Let's start with MCVE. Once you provide it people will be more willing to help you out.